# Google Script CSV save subscript characters

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Having difficulty trying to download a csv file from google that has subscript characters.

So the sheet has lots of subscripts like meters² (where it has the 2 on the end)

When viewing in google that is fine, when saving the file as a CSV file on my google drive - then previewing it - the character is still there.

As soon as I download it though - It looses the formatting.

Any ideas on how I can get around this

Thanks

Comment: Share what you've tried - sounds like an encoding issue.

Comment: Don't think it is encoding, think it is something to do with the utf8 format.

Comment: var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName, sheet);
        
        var file = folder.createFile(fileName, csvFile,MimeType.CSV);

Comment: `utf-8` **is** an encoding